# Change auto-renewal subscription swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a button where a user can change a auto-renewal subscription from monthly to yearly (or vice-versa)
Is that possible without the user having to go through the cancel and re-buy? If it is, how would you go about doing it? 
Any thoughts on the matter will be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible using **subscription group**. All you need to do is add your product ID's into a subscription group, for example:

```
group 1 --> prod_monthly, prod_halyearly, prod_yearly.
```

When user change a subscription to other, it automatically upgrade and downgrade within a group and keep only one subscription active at a time.To create an upgrade page, just retrieve all product ID's and show to user. When they switch plan, it will be changed automatically.

When you create a product ID in app store connect, you will see option to create subscription group.

[image]